# How to access a variable inside an handler in other python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

i have created a bot that is runing on main.py with schedule and i have other python file (telegram.py) that receive messages trough telegram to update a flag that is my itention to start and stop the bot in main.py. How can this be achieved? I have tried so many things, but i cant access the STATUS_FLAG from my telegram.py inside my main.py, i always get 0 as value.

My telegram.py file have this content:

```
import requests
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

TG_TOKEN = "TOKEN"

STATUS_FLAG = 0

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=TG_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'stop', 'status', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    """
    This handler will be called when user sends `/*` command
    """
    global STATUS_FLAG
    print(message['text'])
    if message['text'] == "/start":
        if STATUS_FLAG == 0:
            STATUS_FLAG = 1
            await message.reply("I'm going to start bot")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is already running")
    if message['text'] == "/stop":
        if STATUS_FLAG == 1:
            STATUS_FLAG = 0
            await message.reply("I'm going to stop bot")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is already stoped")
    if message['text'] == "/status":
        print(STATUS_FLAG)
        if STATUS_FLAG == 0:
            await message.reply("Bot is stopped")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is running")
    if message['text'] == "/help":
        text = "/start - Start the bot\n"
        text += "/stop - Stop the bot\n"
        text += "/status - Get bot status"
        await message.reply(text)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    # old style:
    # await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    print(message.text)
    await message.answer(message.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Can someone please guide me trough the correct way of doing this? Thank you so much.

I already tried to define a get function inside telegram.py and call it inside main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is the answer.
You simply **return the flag** to the function and output the flag where you need them.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'stop', 'status', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    """
    This handler will be called when user sends `/*` command
    """
    global STATUS_FLAG
    print(message['text'])
    if message['text'] == "/start":
        if STATUS_FLAG == 0:
            STATUS_FLAG = 1
            await message.reply("I'm going to start bot")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is already running")
    if message['text'] == "/stop":
        if STATUS_FLAG == 1:
            STATUS_FLAG = 0
            await message.reply("I'm going to stop bot")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is already stoped")
    if message['text'] == "/status":
        print(STATUS_FLAG)
        if STATUS_FLAG == 0:
            await message.reply("Bot is stopped")
        else:
            await message.reply("Bot is running")
    if message['text'] == "/help":
        text = "/start - Start the bot\n"
        text += "/stop - Stop the bot\n"
        text += "/status - Get bot status"
        await message.reply(text)
    return STATUS_FLAG #importantly
```

**Do not forget to import the file**

```
import telegram

@dp.message_handler(commands='list_wins')
async def list_wins_combo(message: types.Message):
    print(await telegram.send_welcome(message)) # your file and function
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'some text', parse_mode='html')
```